# how can I use connection string along with jdbc url

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect oracle with jdbc using the following url

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1522:dev;includeSynonyms=true";
```

But it is throwing the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
<host>:1522:dev;includeSynonyms=true
```

If I am removing the property(includeSynonyms=true) from the url, I am able to connect.

I am using `ojdbc14.jar`

please help me

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: are you really still using Java **1.4** (because that's what the driver is for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (AFAIK) set this as part of the URL. As per the [OracleDriver documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html):

> **Specifying a Database URL and Properties Object**
>
> The following signature takes a URL, together with a properties object
>   that specifies user name and password (perhaps among other things):
>
> ```
> getConnection(String URL, Properties info);
> ```
>
> Where the URL is of the form:
>
> ```
> jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>
> ```
>
> In addition to the URL, use an object of the standard Java Properties
>   class as input. For example:
>
> ```
> java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
> info.put ("user", "scott");
> info.put ("password","tiger");
> info.put ("defaultRowPrefetch","15");
> getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@",info);
> ```

The table that lists the connection properties that Oracle JDBC drivers support includes `includeSynonyms`, so you should be able to do:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<HOST>:1522/dev"
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put ("includeSynonyms", "true");
getConnection (url, info);
```

Untested I'm afraid, and I'm not sure if it works with your driver version. You could also look at setting it later via an
[OracleConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_INCLUDE_SYNONYMS) or [OracleConnectionWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnectionWrapper.html#setIncludeSynonyms_boolean_).

Also not entirely sure that URL form works with the 1.4 driver, though I think it does - you might need to use your original `@<host>:1522:dev` form. And note that in the [easy connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306) format, `dev` refers to the service name rather than the SID, and they might not be the same; check what `lsnrctl status` shows if this is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use URL from `url` variable without changing `<host>` into IP address? If so, then simply change it to address of Oracle server.

You should also read about connecting tp Oracle via JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/basic.htm There is even info about setting connection properties including `includeSynonyms`.

Comment: You wouldn't get the ORA-12505 if it wasn't connecting to the listener, so the host must just be obscured in the question. The message suggests it's trying to interpret the entire `dev;includeSynonyms=true` portion as a SID.

Comment: So it seems that your diagnose with separate property setting is correct.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add a TNS name after the `@` symblol ie if the oracle db tns name is dev it would translate to:

`String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<HOST_IP>:1522:dev;includeSynonyms=true";`

use a forward slash instead of a full colon

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried with that now it is throwing java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: NL Exception was generated

Comment: AFAIK `NL Exception` in this case means that your JDBC url contains a syntax error.

Comment: I've seen the problem and edited appropriately. Are you using the forward slashes before the host ip? Also ensure the name `dev` is the TNS name of the database you wish to connect to.