# How to set custom connection properties on DataSource in Spring Boot 1.3.x with default Tomcat connection pool

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate, ojdbc, tomcat-jdbc

I need to set some specific Oracle JDBC connection properties in order to speed up batch `INSERT`s (`defaultBatchValue`) and mass `SELECT`s (`defaultRowPrefetch`).
I got [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789220/optimizing-jdbc-fetch-size-by-use-of-spring-boots-application-properties) how to achieve this with DBCP (Thanks to M. Deinum) but I would like to:

- keep the default Tomcat jdbc connection pool
- keep application.yml for configuration

I was thinking about a feature request to support `spring.datasource.custom_connection_properties` or similar in the future and because of this tried to pretent this was already possible. I did this by passing the relevant information while creating the DataSource and manipulated the creation of the DataSource like this:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource ds = null;

    try {
        Field props = DataSourceBuilder.class.getDeclaredField("properties");
        props.setAccessible(true);
        DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        Map<String, String> properties = (Map<String, String>) props.get(builder);

        properties.put("defaultRowPrefetch", "1000");
        properties.put("defaultBatchValue", "1000");

        ds = builder.url( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:abc" ).username( "ihave" ).password( "wonttell" ).build();

        properties = (Map<String, String>) props.get(builder);

        log.debug("properties after: {}", properties);
    } ... leaving out the catches ...
    }
    log.debug("We are using this datasource: {}", ds);
    return ds;
}
```

In the logs I can see that I am creating the correct DataSource:

```
2016-01-18 14:40:32.924 DEBUG 31204 --- [           main] d.a.e.a.c.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : We are using this datasource: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@19f040ba{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; ...

2016-01-18 14:40:32.919 DEBUG 31204 --- [           main] d.a.e.a.c.config.DatabaseConfiguration   : properties after: {password=wonttell, driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, defaultRowPrefetch=1000, defaultBatchValue=1000, url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz:1521:abc, username=ihave}
```

The actuator shows me that my code replaced the datasource:

[image]

But the settings are not activated, which I can see while profiling the application. The `defaultRowPrefetch` is still at `10` which causes my `SELECT`s to be much slower than they would be if `1000` was activated.

Comment: Modifying the properties is isn't going to work, those aren't the properties you want to modify...

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought these were the properties passed while connecting to the JDBC driver. What makes them different from what I thought ?

Comment: No they aren't passed while connecting. These are the internal properties used by the `DataSourceBuilder` and contain only a small number of useable properties for internal use.

Comment: You are correct, I stepped this through in the debugger and saw that even if DataSourceBuilder would honor these properties the tomcat jdbc DataSource / ~Proxy does not provide a direct setter for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the pools [connectionProperties](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.html#setConnectionProperties(java.lang.String)) should work. Those will be passed to the JDBC driver. Add this to application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties: defaultRowPrefetch=1000;defaultBatchValue=1000
```

Edit (some background information):

> Note also that you can configure any of the DataSource implementation
>   specific properties via spring.datasource.*: refer to the
>   documentation of the connection pool implementation you are using for
>   more details.

source: [spring-boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource)

Comment: This seems to work for properties that get passed in the jdbc url. In my scenario `defaultRowPrefetch` needs to be passed in a set of `Properties` which is the second parameter used in `getConnection(String url, Properties prop)` and follows right after the jdbc url. But nonetheless thanks for your edit.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40255073/993417) by the lead developer on Spring Boot, as of version 1.4, that property no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

As Spring Boot is EOL for a long time I switched to Spring Boot 2.1 with its new default connection pool Hikari. Here the solution is even more simply and can be done in the application.properties or (like shown here) application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        defaultRowPrefetch: 1000
```

(In a real-life config there would be several other configuration items but as they are not of interest for the question asked I simply left them out in my example)

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information to complement the answer by @Cyril. If you want to upvote use his answer, not mine.

I was a little bit puzzled how easy it is to set additional connection properties that in the end get used while creating the database connection. So I did a little bit of research.

`spring.datasource.connectionProperties` is *not* mentioned in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). I created an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4971) because of this.
If I had used the [Spring Boot YML editor](http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v370/NewAndNoteworthy.html), I would have seen which properties are supported. Here is what [STS](http://spring.io/tools) suggests when you create an `application.yml` and hit <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>:

[image: Autocomplete for spring.datasource]

The dash does not matter because of [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) but if you interpret it literally the propertys name is `spring.datasource.connection-properties`.

The correct setup in application.yml looks like this:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        connection-properties: defaultBatchValue=1000;defaultRowPrefetch=1000
        ...
```

This gets honored which is proven by my perf4j measurements of mass `SELECT`s.

Before:

> 2016-01-19 08:58:32.604  INFO 15108 --- [           main]
>   org.perf4j.TimingLogger                  : start[1453190311227]
>   time[1377] tag[get elements]

After:

> 2016-01-19 08:09:18.214  INFO 9152 --- [           main]
>   org.perf4j.TimingLogger                  : start[1453187358066]
>   time[147] tag[get elements]

The time taken to complete the SQL statement drops from 1377ms to 147, which is an enormous gain in performance.

Comment: It isn't mentioned because it isn't a general available property. It works because you are using Tomcat JDBC, if you would use for instance Commons DBCP or a HikariCP based pool that property wouldn't be available nor work. It is due to the binding that it works (maybe that is a feature that should be documenten).

Comment: You are correct, for the other connection pools we need an approach you showed in [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789220/optimizing-jdbc-fetch-size-by-use-of-spring-boots-application-properties). But as Tomcat JDBC pool is the default it wouldn't hurt mentioning specific configuration options ;-) I created an issue at github because of this.

Comment: As I tried to make clear there is no default... It depends on the dependencies you have.

Comment: @M.Deinum Perhaps we are just talking about the definition of "default". My definition of "default" in this case is what get's used when I don't select another connection pool dependency. As the default container in Spring Boot is Tomcat you will automatically get Tomcat JDBC pool (unless you change this)

Comment: Code wise there is no default, that is what for me is leading... Detection is always done...

Comment: @M.Deinum To me `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder`s method `findType()` which starts at Tomcat JDBC Pool and stops as soon as it finds a match is default enough. Codewise ;-)

Comment: As of today, Tomcat JDBC is no longer the default pool. Spring Boot now prefers HikariCP.

Answer (score 2):

After digging around in the Tomcat code for a bit, I found that the `dataSource.getPoolProperties().getDbProperties()` is the `Properties` object that will actually get used to generate connections for the pool.

If you use the `BeanPostProcessor` approach mentioned by @m-deinum, but instead use it to populate the `dbProperties` like so, you should be able to add the properties in a way that makes them stick and get passed to the Oracle driver.

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;

@Component
public class OracleConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)bean;
            PoolConfiguration configuration = dataSource.getPoolProperties();
            Properties properties = configuration.getDbProperties();
            if (null == properties) properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("defaultRowPrefetch", 1000);
            properties.put("defaultBatchValue", 1000);
            configuration.setDbProperties(properties);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```