# Send application name when connecting to an Oracle DB using HikariCP in Spring

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot 1.4.7 application that I am currently updating to version 2.0.5. The application connects to an Oracle DB using JDBC using the following configuration:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<db_server>
    username: ${credentials.database.username}
    password: ${credentials.database.password}
    driver-class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class
    platform: oracle
    tomcat:
      connection-properties: v$session.program=${spring.application.name}
```

After updating the application to Spring Boot 2.0.5 the application name sent to the server is `JDBC Thin Client` instead of `${spring.application.name}`. The reason for this seems to be the switch to HikariCP as the default connection pool in Spring 2.x. How would I migrate this configuration to Hikari in a way that allows me to send a custom property for `v$session.program` to the db?

What I have tried:

- Appending `?ApplicationName=<name>` to the JDBC url.
- Solutions mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856811/how-to-set-custom-connection-properties-on-datasource-in-spring-boot-1-3-x-with) Stackoverflow question
- Setting `System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.v$session.program", <name>)`
- Setting `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.v$session.program: <name>` in the application.yml

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This helped my a lot when I tried to set `defaultRowPrefetch` which makes Oracle ojdbc8.jar connections run much more efficiently !

Answer (score 5):

In yaml, the dollar sign is escaped.

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.v$session.program: <name>

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>, vsession.program=<name>}
```

Try this.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties: v$session.program=name
```

Comment: This way it works. Which means everything in yaml is escaped.

Comment: This does not appear to work. You mention "escaping", but don't show anything in your answer that is escaped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reference to `spring.application.name` you have to use it like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        "[v$session.program]": ${spring.application.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using HikariCP pool properties (default pool in Spring Boot 2)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        v$session.program: MyAppName
```

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

For spring application using properties based configuration following syntax worked for me.

> spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties=v$session.program=your_app_name

Somewhat weird syntax, but it worked for me in `OracleDB` & `SpringBoot v2.6`